# Cut audio into pieces automatically

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, audio

I have an audio-file with 1000s of single words, a history of abusing Blender for anything possible and I want to end up with a few 1000 single wav-files containing one word each. I kinda know Python and I'll be able to manage shell-scripts on Linux.

It's not too hard to find the silent gaps with Python automatically and therefore determine start and end of each word but is it possible to export them in one go?

Comment: Maybe ffmpeg is a better solution?
https://superuser.com/questions/931533/ffmpeg-split-a-video-using-silencedetect

Comment: But that'd be cheating o_O